# how to make generate a serial number column after the sorting in datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I want to show the serial number in a separate column. I have tried the below code, but after ordering it's not showing the sequential serial number. the first column I'm trying to make a serial number column.and last column I have done the order by ascending

code

```
$('#NearestDtr').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            "bDestroy": true,
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ],
            "ordering": true,
            data:"---",
 columns: [
                {
                    "title": "Sl.",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                    }
                },
              
                { title: "latitude", data: "latitude" },
                { title: "longitude", data: "longitude" },
                {
                    title: "Distance (km)", data: "latitude",
                    render: function myfunction(data, type, row, meta) {
                        var dtr = calcCrow(pointA_lat, pointA_long, row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
                        return dtr
                    }
                }
            ],
            "order": [[3, 'asc']]
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "serial number", here? Do you mean you want the first visible row in the table to always have the number "1", regardless of sorting and filtering? I am not sure what you are trying to achieve with `meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1`.

Comment: with meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1 im showing the records with 1 to 55 serial number . but my serial number is coming like 5,23,6,8....., because I have applied for an order in the last column. so first it's generating sl.no then it's ordering the rows in ascending.i want to show all records with sl.no after its applied ordering of column no-3. I'm trying to find the nearest locations with serial number.

Comment: @andrewjames Do you mean you want the first visible row in the table to always have the number "1", regardless of sorting and filtering? YES

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html